# Changing an input parameter within React component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am going through the code of a project and I see the following code:

```
export const FileLink = React.memo(({ url, data, ext, linkContent }) => {
    ...
    ...

  if (!url.includes('?')) {
    url += '?' 
  }
  if (!url.endsWith('?')) {
    url += '&' 
  }
  return <a href={`${url}file_format=${ext}`}>{linkContent}</a>
})
```

It is working fine and no bugs appear in app behavior. But `url` is a passed parameter and it is changed within the `FileLink`: from what I read `React` components should be pure functions. So, I wonder whether its ok to do that, under which circumstances, and if not - why? What can go wrong? Any examples of how it could mess up the app?

(If interested to see the full code: https://github.com/broadinstitute/seqr/blob/8b4419285dfac9365c5c500bbb87b89808c0cedd/ui/shared/components/buttons/ExportTableButton.jsx#L37)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url` is a local variable. Reassigning that variable, which is all this code is doing to it, has no possibility of affecting code outside of this function call. It doesn't make the function impure.

Now, if you were passed in an object, and you started mutating that object, then that would break purity. Because if the component that passed you this object is still using it, then it can "see" that change. For example:

```
const Example = ({ someObjectProp }) => {
  someObjectProp.name = 'bob';
}
```

Comment: but `url` is passed in or it becomes local because it is a string and upon passing it into `FileLink` it is copied?

Comment: `({ url, data, ext, linkContent }) => ` This code is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It's the same as `(props) => { let url = props.url // etc`. `url` is a local variable that starts off with the same value as props.url. Reassigning this variable later doesn't have any effect outside the function.